# Get parent node where child = x

Tags: ruby, arrays, nokogiri

I want to return a 'parent' node from an XML source when I find a matching child.

If I search for 'ddd':

```
@doc.xpath('//item[contains(., "ddd")]')
```

I want to return 'Section 2'

I can't find documentation on 'where' type code for Nokogiri.
Is this even possible??

```
<entry>
  <match>
    <field>Section 1</field>
    <child>
      <item>aaa</item>
      <item>bbb</item>
      <item>ccc</item>
     </child>
  </match>
  <match>
    <field>Section 2</field>
    <child>
      <item>ddd</item>
      <item>eee</item>
      <item>fff</item>
     </child>
  </match>
  <match>
    <field>Section 3</field>
    <child>
      <item>hhh</item>
      <item>iii</item>
      <item>jjj</item>
     </child>
  </match>
</entry>
```

Here's a more accurate XML format.
I'd need to go up and down the node tree to get Section 2.
Is that possible?

```
<entry>
  <match>
    <field>
      <foo>Section 1</foo>
    </field>
    <child>
      <item>aaa</item>
      <item>bbb</item>
      <item>ccc</item>
     </child>
  </match>
  <match>
    <field>
      <foo>Section 2</foo>
    </field>
    <child>
      <item>ddd</item>
      <item>eee</item>
      <item>fff</item>
     </child>
  </match>
  <match>
    <field>
      <foo>Section 3</foo>
    </field>
    <child>
      <item>hhh</item>
      <item>iii</item>
      <item>jjj</item>
     </child>
  </match>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in XPath:

```
@doc.xpath("/entry/match[child/item[contains(., 'ddd')]]/field/foo")
```

This is using your second sample. It first finds the `match` elements that have `child/item` descendants where the `item` contains `ddd`, and then finds the `foo` element grandchildren of that `match`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method named as [`#previous_element`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#previous_element-instance_method) :

```
# #xpath gives all the matched nodes as a collection.
@doc.xpath('//child[./item[contains(., "ddd")]]').map do |child|
  child.previous_element.text
end
# #at_xpath gives first matched node
@doc.at_xpath('//child[./item[contains(., "ddd")]]').previous_element.text
# => Section 2
```

`Section 2` is not a *parent* as per the XML you have given, it is the *sibling* node of the `<child>` node.

Tried and tested :

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse <<-XML
<entry>
  <match>
    <field>Section 1</field>
    <child>
      <item>aaa</item>
      <item>bbb</item>
      <item>ccc</item>
     </child>
  </match>
  <match>
    <field>Section 2</field>
    <child>
      <item>ddd</item>
      <item>eee</item>
      <item>fff</item>
     </child>
  </match>
  <match>
    <field>Section 3</field>
    <child>
      <item>hhh</item>
      <item>iii</item>
      <item>jjj</item>
     </child>
  </match>
</entry>
XML

@doc.at_xpath('//child[./item[contains(., "ddd")]]').previous_element.text # => "Section 2"
```

Comment: That's awesome..! My question was a dumbed down version of what I needed, but this is putting me on the right course.. where is this documented? Also... Is there a way to call a parent node by name as what I want in the real world is a new nodes up from my child node.

Comment: @Beertastic I gave the link.

Comment: Sweet... reading up now...
For some reason I thought it was all Nokogiri documentation, not pure Ruby.. thanks..

Comment: I've updated my question... However, locally I@m getting this error: undefined method `previous_element' .. all this is just using standard nokogiri right?

Comment: @Beertastic Well, I don't know your XML structure.. In your case, before the _node_ you searched, there was no sibling element.. that's why you are getting `nil`.. and on which you are calling the method.. that's why error. You need to read your XML well and XPATH also need to be proper. Nothing wrong with _nokogiri_.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easy traverse the tree by using the ".." syntax (similar to directory folders).

So this should work:

```
@doc.xpath('//item[contains(., "ddd")]/..')

or

@doc.xpath('//item[contains(., "ddd")]/../field')
```